# How does one overcome overlapping points without jitter or transparency in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlap, stripchart

I am starting to use ggplot2. I have some small n (about 30 or so) granular data with lots of overlap. Neither jitter nor alpha (transparency) are suitable. Instead a stripchart with stack and offset do it best but I do not know how to do it in ggplot2. Do you know?

To see what the end result should be click on this [graphic](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2180/7/56/figure/F1).

Here is the script I used a few years ago.

```
stripchart(SystData$DayTo1Syst~SystData$strain,vertical=TRUE,method="stack",pch=19,offset=.3,xlab="Strain",main="Rapidity of Systemic Disease Onset",ylab="Days post inoculation")
```

Comment: Is that just a jitter on the x-axis?

Comment: Yes. The jitter would be just on the x-axis but I do not actually want jitter. I prefer an orderly progression from left to right.

Comment: A sunflower plot could work really well here, though I don't know how simple it is to create them with ggplot2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# your data
df <- data.frame(gp = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each =8), y = sample(1:4,40,replace=TRUE))
# calculate offsets
df <- ddply(df, .(y, gp), transform, offset = (1:length(gp)-1)/20)
qplot(gp, y, data=df) + stat_identity(aes(as.numeric(gp)+offset)) + theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `position_dodge`.

```
df <- data.frame(gp = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each =8), 
                 y = sample(1:4,40,replace=TRUE))
qplot(gp,y,data=df,order=y,position=position_dodge(width=0.5))
```

[alt text http://img100.imageshack.us/img100/8760/dodgel.png](http://img100.imageshack.us/img100/8760/dodgel.png)

Comment: If you look closely, this is not what Farrel wants: position dodge spread all points, while the example figure only spreads overplotted points

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [geom_dotplot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_dotplot.html) from ggplot2

you will probably want to use:

```
ggplot(insert your arguments here) + geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")
```

Hope this helps. The results will look really clean which is what I think you want.